# Why do I keep getting a segmentation fault when passing objects by reference?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to take data from a file and store it in a Object that I have created. I keep running into a segmentation fault, but I am not sure what is causing it. Here is the code:

```
Object<string> populateObj(Object<string>&,string);
string clean(string);
int main(){
  string dictionaryFile;
  ifstream inFile;
  ofstream outFile;
  Object<string> obj1;
  cout << "Enter the name of the Dictionary file" << endl;
  cin >> dictionaryFile;
  obj1 = populateObj(obj1,dictionaryFile);
}
Object<string> populateObj(Object<string> &obj,string fileName){
  ifstream file;
  string words = "";
  file.open(fileName);
  if(file.is_open()){
    while(!file.eof()){
      file >> words;
      obj.add(words);
    }
  }
  else
    cout << "could not open file..." << endl;
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Where are You initializing bag1?

Comment: then don't pass by reference :p  although from the looks of it, this is an XY problem (meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  this code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Random guess, 'Object' can't be copied properly

Comment: oh I mean obj and not bag1 sorry about that.

Comment: Why are you doing this: `obj1 = populateObj(obj1,dictionaryFile)`? Drop the copy. Just use `populateObj(obj1,dictionaryFile)`.

Comment: instead of everyone second guessing.  please tell us: 1 - where the segmentation fault happens.  2 - the implementation of the add method.    3 - implementation of Object's copy constructor.

Answer (score 3):

This may or may not be causing your problem, but this is wrong:

```
if(file.is_open()){
    while(!file.eof()){
        file >> words;
        obj.add(words);
    }
}
```

Try instead:

```
while (file >> words) {
  obj.add(words);
}
```

Your original code tests EOF too early to be useful.

Comment: I tried that and I still get the segmentation fault.

Comment: @user2351234 What about your copy-constructor? Do you have one? Are you handling a resource in your `Object` class? BTW you shouldn't be returning from `populateObj()`. It should be a `void` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(){
  //...
  Object<string> obj1;
  //...
  obj1 = populateObj(obj1,dictionaryFile);
}
Object<string> populateObj(Object<string> &obj,string fileName){
  //...
      obj.add(words);
  //...
  return obj;
}
```

You're unnecessarily overwriting the object. Don't do this. While technically it could work, it's a bad habit (and it points to your copy operator having a bug in it).

Instead, return a reference (if anything) and don't overwrite the object. Also, don't pass in the dictionary string by value, pass it by const reference:

```
int main(){
  //...
  Object<string> obj1;
  //...
  populateObj(obj1,dictionaryFile);
}
Object<string>& populateObj(Object<string> &obj,const string& fileName){
  //...
      obj.add(words);
  //...
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect the problem is in your Object class. If you keep your existing code, and define the object like this, then it runs without error:

```
template<class T> class Object {
public:
    void add(T);
};

template <class T> void Object<T>::add(T val)
{
    cout << "Adding " << val << "\n";
}
```

So you need to look at your Object class to see why it is failing.  The most likely spot would be when the object is copied to return it, and then copied back over the original obj1.  Does that class allocate memory, or use a member variable that isn't copy constructable?

If you take out that unnecessary return of the object you may "fix" the problem by avoiding the copy, but you may want to still fix up the object anyhow as otherwise this problem will probably just surface somewhere else when the object gets copied.